# Eclipse juno : open file but not in a new tab, like in visual studio 2012

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

I would like to know if it possible to open a file just by click on it on Project explorer. I want that action don't open a new tab, like in Visual studio 2012 or Sublime Text.

Is there possible natively or with a plugin ?
Thanks in advance for tips

Answer (score 1):

Like nitind said, change the settings to "Close editors automatically" and set "Number of opened editors before closing" = 1.

And then you can use the "pin the current editor" button to stop the current tab from closing.

You can refer to the following link: (key word: "Pinning editors")
[http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftips%2Fplatform_tips.html](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tips/platform_tips.html)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on file and menu item Open With -> System Editor.

Comment: that's not what I want..
I want open in in eclipse but not in a new tab, if I switch table, he have to disapear

Answer (score 0):

Change the settings on the Editors Preference page to automatically close editors and limit itself to only 1 open editor.

Comment: But I want to be able to double click on my files to open it in tab and just one click to open it and when I go in another file, it close itself